# Why does this update lock the row in Oracle 10?

Tags: c#, oracle, database-connection

Here is the code (with server/passwords etc removed)

```
  public int SetUploadedInESIDatabase(string ID)
        {
            using (var oOracleConn = new OracleConnection())
            {
                oOracleConn.ConnectionString =
                    @"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<ip>)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=<dbname>)));User Id=<user>;Password=<password>;";
                var cmd =
                    new OracleCommand(
                        "UPDATE FOO_ACCESS SET PIMAGE ='-1' WHERE CODE= '" + ID + "'", oOracleConn);

                oOracleConn.Open();



                return  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
```

The effect of this code is it never gets past the return statement. No error is returned (even overnight)

I am not a database expert but our hard pressed DBA says that the connection was being locked (or the row possibly...) he killed the locking connection but still when I run the code it locks up.

Am I doing it wrong(tm) with regards to asking Oracle to update a row?

I realise I should be using a parametrised query but I had an issue with that and needed simple things!
If I copy the built command out of the cmd. with the debugger and run it using SQL Developer then it works (though sometimes it locks up too)

I can select from the database at will.

I am not sure if this is a normal thing or something to do with our environment, so any help is gladly accepted!

Comment: Wow, is that really what an Oracle Connection string looks like in C#?  It actually makes the Java connection strings for Oracle look nice in comparison!

Comment: @ R. Bemrose: That's only what a connection string looks like if you aren't using the Oracle TNSNAMES.ORA file to supply friendly names for servers. Otherwise, using TNSNAMES it looks much nicer: `Data Source=ServerName; User Id=user; Password=pw`.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Oracle supports different connection string formats http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle#p12

Comment: @LBushkin: I know that's what tnsnames.ora looks like, I've just never seen a programming language that uses it for driver connection strings rather than its own format.

Comment: @R.Bemrose: you can specify that connect string to SQL*Plus if you like. It's got nothing to do with C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining @Tony's and @Panagiotis answers, and expanding:

Where do you commit the UPDATE done in this code?  Are you sure it's getting done?

Could this be your scenario:

1. You issue the above UPDATE, but never commit.
2. You don't see your changes, so you try again. Now it hangs.

The row(s) affected by an UPDATE are locked against further updates until committed or rolled back. If you never explicitly commit or rollback, subsequent updates will hang.

If you want to avoid the hang in your code, then execute a

```
SELECT... FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;
```

before you do the UPDATE. If the record is locked, the select will return an error, which you can catch and process.

Have your DBA try this query (Tom Kyte be thanked):

```
select
      (select username from v$session where sid=a.sid) blocker,
       a.sid,
      ' is blocking ',
       (select username from v$session where sid=b.sid) blockee,
           b.sid
  from v$lock a join v$lock b on (a.id1 = b.id1 and a.id2 = b.id2)
 where a.block = 1
   and b.request > 0;
```

To see all the queued up blocks on sessions.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have found the problem (see my 'answer' elsewhere) however this method of making it error if it cannot get the row to update is helpful so you get the cookie :)

Answer (score 1):

- Find out what exactly is locked (table, row, etc)
- Can you execute the statement from
  sqlplus or sqldeveloper using the
  same credentials?
- Are any triggers attached to the 
  table FOO_ACCESS?

Comment: Thanks. I can run the query from sqldeveloper and it *sometimes* works... in code it *never* works. I will get onto the helpful DBA for the rest :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the parameter `studentID` is truly just an ID? What if it was a [malformed bit of SQL that someone tries to inject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)?

It's entirely possible that som unsanitized input has made it's way into `studentID` - and causes your query to do something other than what you expect.

For instance, if `studentID = "'; DROP ALL TABLES; --"` you may have a problem...

Using string concatentation as a means to create a SQL statement is an unsafe practice - and one that is entirely unecessary. It is quite easy to use parameters in SQL commands in .NET, which makes the SQL less susceptible to injection attacks and also improves their performance (by reducing the need to perform statement parsing).

Here's an example that uses parameters:

```
var cmd = new OracleCommand( 
       "UPDATE FOO_ACCESS SET PIMAGE = '-1' WHERE CODE = :code", oracleConn );
cmd.Parametes.Add( ":code", studentID );

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Beyond that, you can investigate what is causing your query to perform poorly by using the V$XXX tables in Oracle to explore what is going on. If you think you have a lock, you can query the [`v$lock`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/dynviews_1123.htm) table to see which tables are locked by which sessions.

Comment: I am in development at the moment so no wild types can try and get me. I will of course only let parametrised things out in the wild! (as i said in my question :) I don't have the privalages to see the v$lock table, so back to the dba it is!

Comment: I have now parametrised my query :D It was as simple as you say, however it makes debugging a tiny bit harder in Visual Studio as VS does not seem to build the final command where you can see it, thus I could not copy and paste the generated sql command into another program for testing.

Answer (score 1):

If one session issues this update and doesn't commit or roll back, the row is locked by that session until it does (commit or roll back).  Could that be what is happening to you?

Comment: This sounds likely but why is it not committing or rolling back if the UPDATE fails... can I hint to it that I would like it to stop trying at some point?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried opening the connection before creating the command object?

Comment: This seems to have no effect. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle will lock a row if multiple writers try to touch it at the same time. Is some other code trying to modify the row or the table at the same time? Have you perhaps executed a SELECT FOR UPDATE statement in another open connection?

Comment: The UPDATE is the only SQL I run... 

I don't know about SELECT FOR UPDATE ... is it something I SHOULD be doing?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried specifying the isolation mode by creating a transaction e.g.

```
using(OracleTransaction transaction = oOracleConn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead)
{

cmd.Transaction = transaction

return  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: No... is RepeatableRead what i want? Looking at the enum maybe .Chaos :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious about one thing.  Can you try changing your return statement so that it's outside the using block?

i.e. instead of:

```
using (..snip...) {

  return  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

try

```
int rv;
using () {

  rv = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
return rv;
```

Comment: It never gets to the return statement, staying stuck in the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() stage.

Comment: What happens if you replace the sql with a simple select - i.e. select count(*) from foo_access?  Is there a reason you're not using the tnsnames.ora to resolve the connection?

Comment: Select worked fine. I am not using tnsnames.ora as I don't know anything about Oracle and the dba knows nothing about programming, and I am doing anything that works or seems to work :O

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was me not quite understanding my tools.

I believe that SQL Developer was creating the lock at some point, and then when I ran my web application to update the same row it was being locked. In my frustration and ignorance I force closed SQL Developer leaving a lock stuck in the database, and I was unable to clear it without DBA super powers.

Having now had the lock cleared and closed all running copies of SQL Developer cleanly the code as I first posted it now works. (phew!)

Thanks for all your help, especially the idea of SELECT FOR UPDATE to see if my update is going to be refused before I issue it :)

Comment: When you do an update in sqldeveloper, you need to explicitly commit the transaction.  There is a setting to auto-commit, but if you turn that on, I promise you that some day, you will regret it.